# Why root cannot access ".android_secure" directory on external SD card?

Tags: security, external-sd, storage, app2sd, file-permissions

I have an Android 9 tablet, rooted by way of Magisk. It has an external SD card mounted as `sdfat` on `/mnt/media_rw/1234-5678` which is mounted on four other mount points, all as type `sdcardfs`, with some variation in owner and group.

From a terminal window I type `ls -al /storage/1234-5678`. Lots of files and directories are shown with one error message:

```
ls: permission denied: .android_secure
```

I try as root. I get the same result. Using `/mnt/media_rw/1234-5678` and root, I can see the entry for `.android_secure`. I'm told that `.android_secure` itself is empty.

1. The external SD card is FAT32.  Anything on it has the same set of permissions.  How is `.android_secure` different from everything else on the card?
2. Even if `.android_secure` has different permissions from the other files in the directory, why is that stopping me from *displaying* the directory entry?
3. I become root and I still can't even display the directory entry for `.android_secure`. How can that be?

I tried `stat`. I tried `lsattr`. Still: `permission denied`.

I have read [What does /mnt/asec directory contain?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155565) but it doesn't answer my questions:

1. If I have the permissions needed to list some directory entries, how am I being forbidden to list a specific entry in that directory?
2. How is it ever possible to deny root the ability to list a directory entry?  (And then change the protections on that entry.)

I can accept that the magic filesystem and/or SELinux makes it possible to have different protections on one file.  I just can't understand root being unable to even see *what* those different protections are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does /mnt/asec directory contain?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155565/what-does-mnt-asec-directory-contain)

Comment: @alecxs I don't believe it addresses my questions.

Comment: you can't change the permissions `------` because the way it is mounted https://askubuntu.com/questions/429848

Answer (score 2):

A quick search reveals that there exist similar unanswered questions ([this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98701), [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130687) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520799)). Let me try to demystify it, starting with brief history.

### WHAT IS `.android_secure` DIRECTORY?

In order to solve the problem of space shortage in internal storage, `app2sd` (*Move to SD Card*) was Android's native feature up to Lollipop. With this method `.apk` files (or whole `/data/app/<pkg>/` directories) are moved as encrypted [`.asec`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98701) files to `.android_secure` folder on external SD card or *internal* `sdcard` partition (mounted at `/mnt/sdcard/` or `/mnt/media_rw/sdcard[N]/`). On every boot `.android_secure` is bind mounted to `/mnt/secure/asec/` and the (`ext4`) filesystem containers (`.asec`) are decrypted (using `dm-crypt`) and mounted to individual directories (named after package names) in a temporary filesystem mounted at [`/mnt/asec/`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r38/Volume.cpp#77) by `vold`. Symlinks from `/data/app/<pkg>/` and possibly `/data/data/<pkg>/lib/` are pointing towards `/mnt/asec/<pkg>/` and `/mnt/asec/<pkg>/lib/`.

### WHY ACCESS TO `.android_secure` IS RESTRICTED?

From the early days of Android, access to `android_secure` folder (which later became `.android_secure`) was restricted. The [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/3bb6020e461e8872e8df0775cba6eb32e06b93ec) states:

> *In order to protect the `/android_secure` directory on VFAT removable media from being mucked with by 3rd party applications on the device, we hide the directory with a read-only, zero-sized `tmpfs` mounted on-top.*

Later in Android 4.4 when FUSE was started being used for [emulating SD cards](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/ba6ae8db137d012c9b8e11f9f8321c7771698e92) from original mount point (`/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1`) to user accessible path (`/storage/sdcard1/`), the zero-sized `tmpfs` functionality ([*Ignore attempts to access security sensitive files*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/977a9f3b1a05e6168e8245a1e2061225b68b2b41)) was [shifted to `sdcard`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/977a9f3b1a05e6168e8245a1e2061225b68b2b41/sdcard/sdcard.c#495) daemon which was used to mount FUSE. In Android 6 the `app2sd` method was [abandoned](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214568/218526) in favor of Adoptable Storage (also filesystem UUID was included in mount points).

In Android 7 `sdcardfs` support was added in parallel to FUSE and the *"Always block security-sensitive files"* functionality was [added to `sdcardfs`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/fd3ea299c5f1d12e13852cc80c4a2639bf9e8a70/fs/sdcardfs/packagelist.c#127) in kernel. In Android 9 FUSE was completely removed (from `sdcard` daemon) but the `sdcardfs` still blocks creation/deletion of `.android_secure` directories in the root of emulated filesystem. However as you noticed, it's possible to access the path through original non-emulated mount point i.e. `/mnt/media_rw/[UUID]/.android_secure`.

For details on filesystem emulation, see [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526.)

### WHY ROOT CAN'T ACCESS A DIRECTORY?

> How is it ever possible to deny root the ability to list a directory entry?

`root` is nothing but kernel's dear user. Kernel doesn't stop UID 0 from doing any harm or good. But there are things which are dearer to kernel than root. It includes SELinux <sup>1</sup>, Linux [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) <sup>2</sup> and obviously the filesystem restrictions like we see with FUSE <sup>3</sup> and `sdcardfs` <sup>4</sup>. And like root cannot delete a file with `immutable` attribute <sup>5</sup>. It's possible to remove any such restriction or add more by modifying kernel source.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [explanation](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216519/218526) and [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128841/262728).
<sup>2</sup> A simple demonstration:

```
~# setpriv --bounding-set -sys_admin -- sh -c 'id; mount -o ro,remount /'
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
```

<sup>3</sup> FUSE [documentation](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/74596e2929c9b9b065f90d04ab7a2232652c64c4/README.md#security-implications):

> *"No other user (**including root**) can access the contents of the mounted filesystem"*

<sup>4</sup> UID 0 is checked [after](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/fd3ea299c5f1d12e13852cc80c4a2639bf9e8a70/fs/sdcardfs/packagelist.c#141) filename (`.android_secure`) is checked.
<sup>5</sup> [Why can't I delete this file as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206594/262728)

---

**RELATED:**

- [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526)
- [How to save files to external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526)